# stamp error with lidar

Tags: c++, lidar, ros-noetic

This is a problem that occurred while connecting and using the YDLIDAR X2 lidar sensor to the Raspberry Pi.

https://github.com/YDLIDAR/ydlidar_ros_driver

I use this package.
it worked normally on other Raspberry Pis.

[image]

I understand stamp as current time (seconds) data, but I wonder if this is correct.

Also, it is presumed that the stamp value is too large, overflowing and malfunctioning. Is there a solution?

I'm curious about the difference from other Raspberry Pis.

Comment: Please do not post images of terminal text. We prefer that you copy/paste the text and format it as code.

Comment: Did you compile this driver yourself, or get a binary from somewhere else?

Comment: I don't see code in the driver to generate this message, so where is it coming from? I assume you know that LaserScan.header.stamp is a ros::Time object, NOT an integer?

Comment: I found the code at https://github.com/YDLIDAR/YDLidar-SDK/blob/fdb7d1beb43a39fd6e7deced11ef4cd16156ee3f/src/YDlidarDriver.cpp#L1129.
I compiled this SDK and driver.